# Cell not updating in Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell (call it cell A1) that is referring to another cell in a column containing dates. Whenever I update the reference in A1 to pick up another date in the column containing dates, it does not update. It either returns a blank or does not change the previous date.

I do have it set at automatic calculation.

The only way it updates is if I move my cursor to select another tab and then I return to the tab in question. Moving between tabs seems to trigger a recalculation.

Why?

I am concerned that all parts of my spreadsheet is not being updated - an uneasy feeling.

Comment: Please provide a small example, where we can reproduce the issue, that way we can attempt to figure out what's going on

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening the spreadsheet to see if the problem persists?

Comment: When updating the reference in A1 did you press enter after (accept the changes) or go to another cell?